# Get process name behind a window

Tags: scripts, window, wmctrl

I'm trying to make a script that checks if Spotify is closed. I tried the following to print the number of open Spotify windows, but it doesn't work.

```
wmctrl -l | grep "Spotify" | wc -l
```

The reason is because when Spotify is playing music, the window title changes to the name of the song that is playing, and it does not include "Spotify".

I was thinking I could do something like the following to print the number of open Spotify windows:

```
wmctrl -l | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I id ... | wc -l
```

But I'm not sure what command I can use to check the name of the process that would be running a window, given the window ID returned from wmctrl (in the form 0x06200001)

Comment: Related: [What process created this X11 window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5478/3330)

Answer (score 1):

```
wmctrl -l | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -i xprop -id {} | grep WM_CLASS\(STRING\)\ =\ \"spotify\" | wc -l
```

I used xargs to run `xprop -id <window-id>` on each open window, and for every Spotify window, the output of `xprop` would show (among lots of other stuff) a line like this:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "spotify", "Spotify"
```

So I piped xprop into `grep WM_CLASS(STRING) = "spotify"`, obvoiusly escaping the spaces, quotations and brackets.